# How to trace and debug routing in Blazor (server side)

Tags: debugging, routes, blazor

Something strange happens with routing in my Blazor application. If I put wrong URL like http://localhost:57222/xxxx - error in URL captures and processed normally, but if I put wrong URL like http://localhost:57222/xxxx/yyyy - Blazor engine not found anything, even http://localhost:57222/xxxx/yyyy/_framework/blazor.server.js, as a result I can not see a correct page "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."
In other case I try to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI with Blazor, but I can not receive debugging message "Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login" I expected and I have no redirection to Identity.UI components.
I have configured route in the same way

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("admin_route", "Admin", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("identityUI_route", "Identity", "Identity/Account/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

Admin panel and main branch without Areas working fine, but (1) something strange happens in error handling and (2) I have not call Identity.UI.
How is possible to trace and debugging this issue?